# Estimated sample size comes out negative

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, sampling, confidence-interval

I consider the study of sleep after coffee. I know that

- standard deviation = 3.5 (hours of sleep)
- if the difference between the hours of sleep was at least 1.5h on average, this would be significant

I wanted to estimate the study size required to have an 75 % probability of detecting such a difference between, at a 1 % significance level.

I tried using this formula for sample size:

n = [Z-score^2 * sd * (1-sd)]/ confidence interval^2

But because 1-sd = -2.5 the whole expression becomes smaller than zero. Is there sth I do wrong?

Comment: Why `sd*(1-sd)` instead of `sd^2`? you may be confusing with the variance of a binomial distribution `p (1-p)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several important things are not clear to me from
your statement of the Question. So I will make
some assumptions that I hope will be helpful
toward a solution. Even if not exactly correct,
my assumptions may point you in the right
direction. At the very least, I hope my Answer
gives you the opportunity to explain your
situation more fully.

- In what follows I am relying heavily on the following sentence in your Question "I wanted to estimate the study size required to have an 75 % probability of detecting such a difference between, at a 1 % significance level."
- Not so much on your attempted answer.

It seems you want
a 'power and sample size' computation for
a paired t test (one-sample t test on differences)
and that you are testing $H_0: \delta = 0$ against
$H_a: \delta > 0,$ where $\delta$ is the average
decrease in hours of sleep in the population
from drinking coffee.

You assume the population
SD is $\sigma = 3.5,$ you want to reject $H_0$ against specific alternative $H_a: \delta = 1.5$ in a test at the 1% level. The question is in how many subjects $n$ do you need to find the loss of sleep
$d$d from drinking coffee.

For clarity, let's look at *one* fictitious sample
of $n = 40$ differences $d_i,$ as follows:

```
d = rnorm(40, 1.4, 3.5)
summary(d)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
 6.351450  0.001869  1.851865  1.722092  4.005881  6.983483 
 length(d);  sd(d)
[1] 40            # sample size
[1] 3.103335      # sample SD
```

Then the proposed t test (in R) gives the following
output. Because the P-value is $0.0006 > 0.01 = 1\%$ the test rejects at the 1% level.

```
t.test(d, mu = 0, alt="gr")

        One Sample t-test

data:  d
t = 3.5096, df = 39, p-value = 0.0005744
alternative hypothesis: 
  true mean is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.8953566       Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 1.722092
```

Of course, this one fictitious dataset cannot
provide evidence that $n = 40$ is enough subjects.
For one thing, our data have sample SD about $3.1,$
which happens to be smaller than the assumed population $\sigma = 3.5.$

However, one can look at 100,000 such datasets
to see what rejection rate we get. Is it the
required 75%? A little experimentation shows that
to get a power of 75% we need about $n = 52.$

```
set.seed(2022)
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(52,1.5, 3.5), 
                mu=0, alt="gr")$p.val)
mean(pv <= .01)
[1] 0.75495
```

*Notes:* (1) The numerical vector `pv` contains P-values from
100,000 P-values, the logical vector `pv <= .01` contains
100,000 `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s, and its `mean` is
its proportion of `TRUE`s (rejections).

(2) Many mathematical statistics texts give an exact
formula, involving non-central t distributions,
to find power for a given sample size. Also, there
are online calculators and software packages
that do exact 'power and sample size' computations.

(3) Your attempted Answer seems to use
the formula for a confidence interval,
I don't see how that leads to what you say you want.

(4) Usually coffee leads to *loss* of sleep,
so I think you need a one-sided procedure. (A two-sided test
would require more observations than a one-sided test.)